# Unable to edit .less file dynamically using dotless

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, less, dotless

I've installed dotless and i see the handler has been added to my web.config file. However, i am unable to make changes to the .less file dynamically and reload the page and see the effect of the changes...Is there some setting I need to turn on? This is the handler:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a line of code in your Web.config looking like this:

```
<dotless minifyCss="false" cache="true" web="false" />
```

If you cannot find this line then add it, but change the *cache="true"* part to *cache="false"*